# Using aspnet core SignalR client for VSIX project

Tags: asp.net, signalr, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, signalr-client

I have an issue when I try to build connection for SignalR hub from VSIX project.

Visual studio 2022

VSIX project:
TargetFramework: .Net framework 4.7.2

Signal R lib
Lib name: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
version: 7.0.5

```cs
// MyCoolCommand.cs

/// <summary>
/// Command handler
/// </summary>
internal sealed class MyCoolCommand
{
   // some init code. I did change nothing
   private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      var url = "http://localhost:9200/myHub";

      // will fail
      var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
         .WithUrl(url)
         .WithAutomaticReconnect()
         .Build();
    }
}
```

Exception info:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

How to repeat in your local machine:

1. create VSIX project
2. add command
3. add Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client from nuger
4. in your command copy code from this example
5. run
6. I tried to change .net framework version - didn't helped
7. `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` is one of sub deps for 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client'. I double checked and this lib is exist in the output after build.
8. I also tried to add `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` manually to the place where devenv.exe lives.
   after this I started to see the same exception but in this time `System.Runtime` is missing.

I think it somehow releated with runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
In my case changing the version of signal r client helped.
From 7.0.5 to 7.0.0.

Maybe it somehow related with avaliable runtime on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing .NET Framework and .NET CORE libraries that are not compatible with each other.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-7.0) explains the differences between the two.

Follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) for using .NET Framework version. Here is the repo as well - https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment.
I've just checked and the lib should work with dotnet framework as well. You can also check it in avaliable frameworks. 

Additionally I created .net framework 4.7.2 console application and added the lib. It works smoothly. 

So I belieive that this is not a case.